# FormData populated with files sometimes fails without any server response

Tags: php, apache, firefox

A web site is sending requests to a server with XMLHttpRequest and FormData object. Files are added to it. It works fine most of the time but sometimes, it fails with no message from server, no headers, nothing is received. The network monitor shows request headers but not response headers and I can't get any HTTP error code, it is empty !? If I retry this request multiple times, it succeed.

The problem seems to happen with Firefox (103.0b7), 102 and 101. I've also tried to reproduce with portable versions of Firefox 97, 100 and 101 but I can't.
I can't reproduce it with Vivaldi (5.3.2679.68) or Edge (103.0.1264.49).

I've checked the Apache and FPM logs.

FPM access log says : `error 500`

Apache access log says : `error 400`

Apache error log says : `proxy_fcgi:error (103) Software connection abort: [client IP-Address:port] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (reading input brigade), referer : sender-url` (I've replaced real `IP-Address:port` and `sender-url`).

Here is the server configuration even if I don't think the problem is here :

```
$> php -v
PHP 7.4.28 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2022 16:17:19) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

$> apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)
Server built:   2022-03-14T16:28:35
```

Is there something else I can check to find the problem ?

**[EDIT]**

It seems to be resolved with Firefox versions 104 and later. On 103 the bug was still there.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem. It happens not only in XHR requests but also when uploading multiple files through simple plain old forms. I believe it's a bug somewhere in Firefox' request composition. I have submitted bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1785197

Comment: Thank's for your bug submission, it seems to be resolved after update from v103 to v104. It was really a Firefox bug.

Comment: Yep, it's all working now. Happy to help.